# Loading webpack bundle via script tag for microfrontend approach

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4, micro-frontend

I'm following a couple articles on how to implement a simple micro-frontend approach with React ([here](https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-develop-microfrontends-using-react-step-by-step-guide-47ebb479cacd) and [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/5-steps-to-turn-a-random-react-application-into-a-micro-frontend-946718c147e7), see sample repos at bottom of question).

It works perfectly when the two apps (the root app, and the subapp) are running in their respective developoment servers.  However, when I deploy the build artifacts to the real web server, it doesn't work.  This is the important code in the root app:

```
function MicroFrontend({name, host, history}) {

    useEffect(() => {
        const scriptId = `micro-frontend-script-${name}`;

        const renderMicroFrontend = () => {
            window["render" + name](name + "-container", history);
        };

        if (document.getElementById(scriptId)) {
            renderMicroFrontend();
            return;
        }

        fetch(`${host}/asset-manifest.json`)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((manifest) => {
                const script = document.createElement("script");
                script.id = scriptId;
                script.crossOrigin = "";
                script.src = `${host}${manifest.files["main.js"]}`;
                script.onload = () => {
                    renderMicroFrontend();
                };
                document.head.appendChild(script);
            });

        return () => {
            window[`unmount${name}`] && window[`unmount${name}`](`${name}-container`);
        };
    });

    return <main id={`${name}-container`}/>;
}

MicroFrontend.defaultProps = {
    document,
    window,
};
```

When I click on the button that loads the main.js for the micro-app, it works fine up till the point where it calls the `renderMicroFrontend` above.  Then I get this error in my browser:  `Uncaught TypeError: window[("render" + t)] is not a function`

This is because it can't find the function that loads the microfrontend that is supposed to be on `window`.  When I run the two apps in the dev server, I have the correct function on `window` and it works.  When I follow the same steps with the two apps deployed to a real server (after running `npm run build`), instead of having the `renderMicroApp` function on my `window`, I have a different variable called:  `webpackJsonpmicro-app`.

I figured out that this is due to the output.library option (and/or related options) in webpack, from the webpack docs:

> output.jsonpFunction.
> string = 'webpackJsonp'
> Only used when target is set to 'web', which uses JSONP for loading on-demand chunks.
> If using the output.library option, the library name is automatically concatenated with output.jsonpFunction's value.

I basically want the bundle/script to be loaded and evaluated, so that the `renderMicroApp` function is available on the window, but I'm lost regarding what webpack settings I need for this to work, since there are lots of different permutations of options.

For reference, I'm using the following config-overrides in the micro-app (atop `react-app-rewired`):

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, env) => {
    config.optimization.runtimeChunk = false;
    config.optimization.splitChunks = {
      cacheGroups: {
        default: false,
      },
    };

    config.output.filename = "static/js/[name].js";

    config.plugins[5].options.filename = "static/css/[name].css";
    config.plugins[5].options.moduleFilename = () => "static/css/main.css";
    return config;
  },
};
```

And in my index.tsx (in the micro app) I'm exposing the function on the window:

```
window.renderMicroApp = (containerId, history) => {
  ReactDOM.render(<AppRoot />, document.getElementById(containerId));
  serviceWorker.unregister();
};
```

Some sample repos:

- https://github.com/rehrumesh/react-microfrontend-container
- https://github.com/rehrumesh/react-microfrontend-container-cats-app.git
- https://github.com/rehrumesh/react-microfrontend-container-dogs-app

Comment: Not able to load images and scss file, any suggestion how can I resolve?

Answer (score 0):

You could try with [terser-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/terser-webpack-plugin).

```
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, env) => {
    config.optimization.minimize = true;
    config.optimization.minimizer = [new TerserPlugin({
      terserOptions: { keep_fnames: true }
    })];

    config.optimization.runtimeChunk = false;
    config.optimization.splitChunks = {
      cacheGroups: {
        default: false,
      },
    };

    config.output.filename = "static/js/[name].js";

    config.plugins[5].options.filename = "static/css/[name].css";
    config.plugins[5].options.moduleFilename = () => "static/css/main.css";
    return config;
  }
};
```

Comment: So you're saying the problem is that the function names aren't being kept?  Shouldn't public functions always keep the function names?  If I put a function on the window variable like here below shouldn't that always be kept?:
window.renderSubApp = (containerId, history) => {
  ReactDOM.render(<AppRoot />, document.getElementById(containerId));
  serviceWorker.unregister();
};